# How to use expand.grid with conditions?

Tags: r

I am using expand.grid of a series of variables, but there are some special cases that can be excluded.
A search showed that expand.grid cannot do this, but filters can be added so here is my attempt.

```
a = 1:5
b = 1:5
c = 0:3
d = 1:5
e = 1:3
df = expand.grid(a,b,c,d,e)
colnames(df)[c(1:5)] <- c("a","b","c","d","e");
df$d = ifelse(df$c == 0, d[[1]], df$d);
df$e = ifelse(df$c == 0, d[[1]], df$e);
df = unique(df)
```

I this case variables d and e are not used if c is 0 so I use ifelse to set d and e to the first value of d and e if c = 0, and then remove duplicated rows with unique.

The code above does actually work, so what is wrong with it. It is too specific.

I don't like the 2 ifelse statements for specific variables. What if I have 100 conditional variables. How can compact the statement and maybe write all conditions or variables dependent on any one condition in only one line.

I also welcome any other optimizations to do the desired task with minimal coding for complicated scenarios. Thank you.

**Update**

As far a the number of variables, I simply don't know before run-time. My example is a very basic case. Very often I get great solutions, but ones that only work for the specific example and not the true problem.

I don't have the sets a through e or know how many sets or the size of the sets I have until the run-time.
a could be a list of folders, b a list of sub folders, c files. but if files are small empty or something else, I don't need to do e and f.

The ideal solution does not look at any static values such as:

expand.grid(list_of_variables, key_variables = key_values, list_of_dependents)

Yes this is beyond the scope of this question, but I just trying to say is the solution needs to work on sets of data not known at the time of coding.

Hopefully this clears up some things instead of just raising more questions.

Comment: Can't you just do `df <- df[df$c != 0,]`?

Comment: doesn't it just remove the row if c = 0, I need the c = 0, just for it to appear only once, for each of the other variables.

Comment: Sure. It would help a lot if you provided a smaller sample (not `5*5*4*5*3` rows) and your intended output. And since you mention *"100 conditional variables"*, that's a little vague, can you clear that up too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another base R way. It uses a logical index to modify columns `d` and `e`, the rest of the code is like in the question. The tests below show it's the fastest alternative.

```
f1 <- function(a, b, c, d, e){
  X <- expand.grid(a, b, c, d, e)
  names(X) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
  X$d <- ifelse(X$c == 0, X$d[1], X$d)
  X$e <- ifelse(X$c == 0, X$d[1], X$e)
  unique(X)
}

f2 <- function(a, b, c, d, e){
  X <- expand.grid(a, b, c, d, e)
  names(X) <- c("a","b","c","d","e")
  i <- X$c == 0
  X$d[i] <- X$d[1]
  X$e[i] <- X$e[1]
  unique(X)
}

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

f3 <- function(a, b, c, d, e){
  crossing(a, b, c, d, e) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(d, e), ~ replace(., c == 0, first(.))) %>%
    distinct
}

a = 1:5
b = 1:5
c = 0:3
d = 1:5
e = 1:3

library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  op = f1(a,b,c,d,e),
  rui = f2(a,b,c,d,e),
  akrun = f3(a,b,c,d,e)
)

print(mb, unit = "relative", order = "median")
#Unit: relative
#  expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   rui 1.0000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100  a 
#    op 0.8147996 1.035322 1.018649 1.026295 1.038269 1.096384   100  a 
# akrun 1.7580304 1.815582 1.836061 1.827887 1.872767 1.107545   100   b
```

Comment: I like f2 first find the conditions and then use them. Is it possible to set in only one command such as: **X[i,c("d","e")] <- get(c("d","e"))[[1]]** the select works, but the get which should grab the vector elements does not. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelE Yes, it is possible but in my tests `f2` became slower than the question's solution `f1`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
crossing(a, b, c, d, e) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(d, e), ~ replace(., c == 0, first(.))) %>%
    distinct
```